# Check win function diagonal for connect 4 is not working

Tags: c++

Hey guys I wrote a connect four program in C++ but Im having trouble figuring out the issue with my algorithm for finding out the winning move diagonally. Here is the code that I wrote: My horizontal and vertical functions work though

```
//checks for a horizontal win
    //returns 1 if there's a win
    for(int i=0;i<numrows;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<rowsize-3;j++)
            if(board[i][j]!=" " && board[i][j]==board[i][j+1] && board[i][j]==board[i][j+2] && board[i][j]==board[i][j+3])
                return 1;

    //checks for a vertical win
    //returns one if theres a win
    for(int i=0;i<numrows-3;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<rowsize;j++)
            if(board[i][j] !=" " && board[i][j]==board[i+1][j] && board[i][j]==board[i+2][j] && board[i][j]==board[i+3][j])
                return 1;  



    int numrows=6;
    int rowsize=7;

//checks the right side of a diagonal for a  win
    for(int i=0;i<numrows;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<rowsize;j++)
            if(board[i][j] !=" " && board[i][j]==board[i+1][j+1] && board[i][j]==board[i+2][j+2] && board[i][j]==board[i+3][j+3])
                return 1;


    //checks left diagonal win for a win
    for(int i=0;i<numrows;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<rowsize;j++)
            if(board[i][j] !=" " && board[i][j]==board[i+1][j-1] && board[i][j]==board[i+2][j-2] && board[i][j]==board[i+3][j-3])
            return 1;

//creates a typical 7 by 6 connect four board
    for (int i=0;i<numrows; i++){
        vector<string> row;

        for (int j=0;j<rowsize; j++)
            row.push_back(" ");
        board.push_back(row);
    }
```

Comment: Is it erroring or just not recognizing a diagonal?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: It's not recognizing the diagonal. I think it has something to do with my for loop because I'm pretty sure the if statement is correct!

Comment: what case is it not picking up? i.e. where is the diagonal

Comment: It only gets the diagonal if one of the pieces is in the last row but otherwise if i try to make a diagonal where none of the pieces are in the last row then it wont recognize the diagonal

Comment: weird, i replicated your situation with an `int[][]` array and it works.. http://cpp.sh/9irfa

Comment: That's weird because I know all my pieces are placed correctly inside the vector!

Comment: I tried it again with `std::string[][]` and it doesn't work. So it has something to do with the string array

Comment: @Chara I added some more functions from my program. Only the horizontal and vertical works perfect!

Comment: i noticed you added bounds for vertical/horizontal, why not do it for the diagonals too?

Comment: @chara Orginally I had a bound: for(int i=0;i<numrows-3;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<rowsize-3;j++)
            if(board[i][j] !=" " && board[i][j]==board[i+1][j-1] && board[i][j]==board[i+2][j-2] && board[i][j]==board[i+3][j-3])
            return 1;

Comment: Yeah, keep that in. It'll save you runtime and prevent UB. Btw for that loop since you're decreasing `j` it should be `int j=3;j<rowsize;j++`

Comment: @chara but it will only work for a diagonal if the pieces are in the 1st 2nd 3rd and 4th row

Comment: lets continue this in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108324/connect4problem)

Comment: @chara i can;t i dont have enough reputation

Comment: :( oh. Okay ElAwDk wants to know if by 1st row you mean the top row, or the bottom row.

Comment: @chara 1st row is bottom row

Comment: http://cpp.sh/2thq here, bounds work

Comment: @chara can I email you my program file?

Comment: I would prefer not to give out my e-mail, can you create a pastebin and link me?

Comment: @chara I don't want to make my code out in public just yet so is there a way I could send it to you without showing people my full code?

Comment: Can't exactly think of a way off the top of my head..

Comment: @chara is it possible for me to delete a file that I uploaded on pastebin? If so I'll send u the link once i upload it and then when u have my files downloaded ill delete it then

Comment: Lol, you could find out if that's possible! Not too familiar with pastebin utility myself. Does the code with the bounds I linked not work?

Comment: @chara no it didn't so ill just let u know when i uploaded it and i will give u the link just let me know when you have it downloaded

Comment: @chara Pastebin wont let me upload my files it will only let me copy and paste the text but I have several files that I did this in. Do you know other websites?

Comment: At this point, I would recommend taking a look at @NathanOliver's comment (2nd one on this post) as I don't have much time to spare. Using a debugger can be very useful!

Answer (score -1):

I think it could be an error since evaluating board[i+x][j+-y] for all the board will get out of bounds of the array.

For example when you have i=4, j=4 the first if statement will look for board board[4][4], board[5][5], board[6][6], board[7][7]

Comment: Since it's C++, its UB, and there won't be an error for array out of bounds. Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why

Comment: Sorry I forgot it was c++ however the UB will happen at the time i or j evaluates on 4 for the first time and as he said only if a piece is on the first row it is recognized. Couldn't it be the reason that the second row is not being evaluated?

Comment: He said that if there is a piece on the last row it is recognized, otherwise it isn't

Comment: Yeah but the last row graphically might be the 0 index. I would have asked the index of the last row but I can't comment on the post

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, it's possible if that's the way he's treating it. After all, UB can be anything :p

Comment: Wouldn't that only be the case if he overloaded the array operator so that the 0 index refers to the last row in the vector though?

Comment: Well normally when you print an array the first row is tinted so it is on the top

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing how that explains why diagonals with a piece in the LAST row are showing (when `i = 5`) but diagonals when `i < 5` are not. Technically it should pick up the piece in the first row, since `i` isn't going out of bounds yet

Comment: I think the problem is still that we don't know what he's calling "last row" because it can be either i=0 or i=5

Comment: You're right, he was referring to bottom row as 1st row

Comment: The numrows-3 and rowsize-3 will do the trick, in his code he's still missing the -3 in some for loops